# ¿Cómo hacer una Función para dar vuelta un string si tiene mas de 5 letras?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Quiero hacer una funcion que tome una oracion de 1 o mas palabras y devuelva la misma oracion con aquellas palabras con un largo igual o mayor a 5 invertidas. Es decir, "hola como estas" ----> "hola como satse"

Esto es lo que tengo hecho:

```
sentence = "hola compañero"

def spin_words(sentence):
   for i in sentence.split():
      if len(i) >= 5:
         return i[::-1]
      else:
         return i

print(spin_words(sentence))

#output = "hola"
```

Por alguna razon al ejecutar la funcion el resultado es simplemente "hola". Alguna idea de que pueda estar pasando?

Comment: Que deberia poner entonces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es que realmente no llegas a iterar sobre la lista de palabras que te retorna `sentence.split()`, a la primer palabra ya haces un `return`. Una forma podría ser guardar cada palabra, modificada o no, en una lista y luego reconformar la oración nuevamente:

```
sentence = "hola compañero"

def spin_words(sentence):
  new_sentence = list()
  for word in sentence.split():
    if len(word) >= 5:
      new_sentence.append(word[::-1])
    else:
      new_sentence.append(word)
  return " ".join(new_sentence)

print(spin_words(sentence))

hola oreñapmoc
```

Incluso, si quieres profundizar en "comprensión de listas", lo anterior se puede escribir de una forma más compacta:

```
new_sentence = " ".join([word[::-1] if len(word) >= 5 else word for word in sentence.split()])
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora entiendo y funciona!